# Whats the best way to parse a stringified array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

For example: '[test,abc,123]'. How do you turn that into a standard javascript array that can be iterated?

Comment: That's not a stringified array. Fix whatever's giving you that essentially broken input so that it gives you JSON instead, then parse the JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, but really you should fix your input to give you real JSON as is noted in the comments.

```js
console.log(JSON.parse('["test","abc",123]'));
```